# Windows 10 search box - Documents tab is empty (no history)

Tags: windows-10

The taskbar search box (or bring it up by Windows-S keyboard combo) has tabs across the top: All, Apps, Documents, etc.

It used to be the case that the Documents tab, when clicked on, would show recently opened documents. Now, it only says "Start typing to search for documents."

I have recent files listed in Quick Access in File Explorer, and in the jump-lists of applications in the taskbar.

My Windows 10 installation is up to date (excepting version 1909, I have not updated to that).

Why would my recently opened files no longer show up under the Documents tab in the Windows search box?

I haven't found an image or video online yet to show exactly what I remember, but I did find this image from February 2020 which shows a document history ("Recent Activities") on the All tab of Windows Search. I don't have that either.

[image]

Comment: The way this works for me currently is that the search starts empty (nothing showing) and then immediately starts to fill as soon as you type. So it is like search used to be more than a list of recent searches. This works well for me (if not for you). Also, it is working this way on 3 different computer here, one of which is Windows Insider V2004

Comment: @John I didn't use the feature I am asking about often, so my memory of it is hazy. But I have now added to my question a picture I found online which shows a document history on the All tab at least. I don't have that either. Do you have that? The picture is from February 2020. It appears to be pulling the history from the Timeline.

Comment: Your setting in the photo is for All and and that shows some recent. Put your setting to Documents and it will start off empty until you search for something

Comment: @John I did not have Recent Activities on the All tab either. But I figured out the issue. There was a Covid-19 resources announcement on the All tab. Once I closed that by clicking on the "X" for that section, the Recent Activities section came back. I think I was remembering Recent Activities on the All tab all along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I was thinking of the Recent Activities section of the All tab of Windows Search, not the Documents tab. See the screenshot in my question.

Recent Activities was not showing in the All Tab of Windows Search for me because it was superseded by a Covid-19 information section. Once I closed that section by clicking on the "X" for that section, the Recent Activities section reappeared on the All tab.